# Resizing AVPlayer in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have an `AVPlayerViewController`, with its `AVPlayer` view added as a subview of a `UIView`. This `UIView` is added to a `UIScrollView`. The idea is to implement a "move and scale" view for the video. I have it working for when the view inside the `UIScrollView` is a `UIImageView`. However, when the view is a `UIView` with an `AVPlayer` subview, the scale of the `UIView` appears too small.

Here's my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController()
    videoPlayerController.videoURL = url
    self.addChildViewController(videoPlayerController)
    videoView.addSubview(videoPlayerController.view)

    videoPlayerController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let left = NSLayoutConstraint(item: videoPlayerController.view, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: videoView, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let right = NSLayoutConstraint(item: videoPlayerController.view, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: videoView, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let top = NSLayoutConstraint(item: videoPlayerController.view, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: videoView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let bottom = NSLayoutConstraint(item: videoPlayerController.view, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: videoView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

    videoView.addConstraints([left, right, top, bottom])

    let asset = AVAsset(url: url)
    let clipVideoTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo).first!
    videoView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: clipVideoTrack.naturalSize.height, height: clipVideoTrack.naturalSize.width)
    setZoomScale()
}

fileprivate func setZoomScale() {
    let widthScale = scrollView.bounds.size.width / videoView.bounds.size.width

    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = widthScale
    scrollView.zoomScale = widthScale
}

func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return videoView
}

func scrollViewDidZoom(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let videoViewSize = videoView.frame.size
    let scrollViewSize = scrollView.bounds.size

    let verticalPadding = videoViewSize.height < scrollViewSize.height ? (scrollViewSize.height - videoViewSize.height) / 2 : 0
    let horizontalPadding = videoViewSize.width < scrollViewSize.width ? (scrollViewSize.width - videoViewSize.width) / 2 : 0
    }

    scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: verticalPadding, left: horizontalPadding, bottom: verticalPadding, right: horizontalPadding)
}
```

What should happen is that the `videoView` should fill the width of the screen and be centred, with the ability to zoom in to it's natural size. Instead the view appears centred but much smaller (maybe 3 times smaller) on the screen. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

***Swift5***

please try this, it will give you the video size you need.

```
    let offsetX = max((scrollView.bounds.width - scrollView.contentSize.width) * 0.5, 0)
            let offsetY = max((scrollView.bounds.height - scrollView.contentSize.height) * 0.5, 0)
            scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: offsetY, left: offsetX, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```